# Can Galaxy S use 802.11n for tethering?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, tethering, wifi-tethering

I have a Galaxy S (GT-I9000) running Darky's ROM 10.1 (Gingerbread 2.3.3). I just noticed that when I use tethering to create a wireless AP, it uses only 802.11g, not 802.11n even though my netbook supports it. Not that I'd need it for the speed, but better signal for crowded places with lots of access points and all the g-channels used.

EDIT: g-channels, not frequencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have read, that even though the GT-i9000 claims to support 802.11n, it does not. I even read that if your router is set to 802.11n "only" mode, the SGS will not connect to the access point. This is why you see the device using 802.11g.

I don't think you can change the channel that is used with the "built in" tether, but some of the 3rd party apps look like they let you change the channel.

Comment: Good to know. As a sidenote, my Galaxy Nexus uses 802.11n by default, so the situation is better with newer phones.